# Select 3 products (product name and order number) sold in the most quantity in one order (in MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Whole db with all tables is in the [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc)

I tried using this code:

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, OrderDetails.OrderID, SUM(Quantity) FROM Products
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
GROUP BY ProductName
ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC
```

But the result was wrong for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, and you need to group by two columns `orderdetails.orderid` and `products.productid`

```
SELECT products.productname,
       products.productid,
       orderdetails.orderid,
       Sum(quantity) AS MaxQuantity
FROM   products
       INNER JOIN orderdetails
               ON products.productid = orderdetails.productid
GROUP  BY orderdetails.orderid,
          products.productid
ORDER  BY maxquantity DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```